# WP get_results query not working?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I've to fetch the records on the basis of some text. For this i am using LIKE query in get_results. But when I run this query into SQL it works fine but into the code it does not. I am not able to find out where the mistake is. Kindly suggest me the right way to do this. here is my code.

```
 $searchTag = $_REQUEST["s"];
 <?php if (have_posts())  :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $current++; ?>
```

here is the problem occurring (the query gives empty results[may be /it doesnot display any thing] )

```
 <?php 
 $post_id = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta 
 WHERE meta_value  LIKE '%,".$searchTag.",%'OR meta_value LIKE '%,".$searchTag."'
 OR meta_value LIKE '".$searchTag.",%' OR meta_value='".$searchTag."'  " );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
global $wpdb;
```

before your query.

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated your issue, you should be using the prefix object.

```
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE meta_value  LIKE '%,".$searchTag.",%'OR meta_value LIKE '%,".$searchTag."' OR meta_value LIKE '".$searchTag.",%' OR meta_value='".$searchTag."'  " );
```